# IOS Parse How to search an array of strings for a substring?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

I am using a parse database to store some records. I am storing an array of strings and I want to be able to search this array for substrings. Here is an example:

Array A:

```
["carbrown","blue","house","coldturkey"]
```

Array B:

```
["racecar","green","walking"]
```

Array C:

```
["greenturkey","users","published","ramp"]
```

I want to be able to search for a substring like `car` and get Arrays A and B as matching results, Or searching for `turkey` gives me matching results with arrays A and C, Or `green` gives me Arrays B and C, and so on..

I know that for strings you can use this in parse:

```
- (void)whereKey:(NSString *)key containsString:(NSString *)substring
```

Is this possible with arrays, maybe something with regex?

Comment: hi @SuperKevin did you found a solution for this question ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use NSPredicate for this purpose. The following is an example.

```
NSArray *a = @[@"carbrown",@"blue",@"house",@"coldturkey"];
NSArray *b = @[@"racecar",@"green",@"walking"];
NSArray *c = @[@"greenturkey",@"users",@"published",@"ramp"];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", @"car"];
NSArray *filteredArrayA = [a filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSArray *filteredArrayB = [b filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSArray *filteredArrayC = [c filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

if ([filteredArrayA count]) {
    NSLog(@"A has car in it");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but these arrays are in the parse system. I am asking how I can pull these matching values from parse, I do not have these arrays in memory.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Not familiar with Parse.